# merge multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, r

I have a list of arrays in which each array has only 2 elements with numbers and otherwise NA. There is only 1 number for any given element in all the arrays combined.

here is some example data.

```
ar1=array(NA,dim=c(2,3,4))
ar1[1,1,1]=100
ar2=array(NA,dim=c(2,3,4))
ar2[2,3,4]=200
ar3=array(NA,dim=c(2,3,4))
ar3[2,1,4]=300
ar=list(ar1,ar2,ar3)
```

Thanks!

Comment: and to clarify, the output should be an array of dim `c(2, 3, 4)` with  three non-NA values?

Comment: In this case yes. In the real case all values will be filled. So basically im looking to replace the NAs into a single master array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Reduce` with any vectorized function that ignores `NA`s:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(!is.na(x), x, y), ar)
```

Another example:

```
library(functional)
Reduce(Curry(pmax, na.rm = TRUE), ar)
```

Comment: As a side comment, I really wish the first anonymous function above came as one of the default binary operators. You can create one by doing `"%|%" <- function(x, y) ifelse(!is.na(x), x, y)`. Then do things like `c(1, NA) %|% c(NA, 2)`.

Comment: @flodel - like the other answer here, I usually just employ `pmax` in those situations - `pmax(c(1, NA),c(NA, 2),na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: I wouldn't want `1 %|% 2` to return `2`. The general function I have in mind would only use the second value if the first one is `NA`. For example `x %|% 0` would replace all NAs in `x` with zeroes. I use the `ifelse` construct everywhere and wish there was a binary operator instead. (I do understand this does not apply here, so `pmax` is fine for the question at hand)

Answer (score 5):

pmax has an na.rm argument and you can pass ar as a list along with that argument to pmax with do.call:

```
> do.call(pmax, c(ar,  na.rm=TRUE) )
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  100   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]  300   NA  200
```